# Registration page

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

WP 4.3 / CiviCrm 4.6.8

CiviContribute - On front end page, ready for a new member to sign up, using custom Profile, it is redirecting to a "Select payment gateway" empty page, after a user fills out his details and hits Contribute (changed to register). There is no Thank You page or confirmation that he is now registered.

All details go into civicrm and admin is notified via email that he signed up with their user name and auto-generated password - and (slowly) a Welcome email does go out to the user. (WP User Accounts are enabled).

I have $0 fee enabled, and test/live PayPal standard included for payment processor (if needed).

For the contribute/registration/sign-up page..it quickly goes through the process and shows a Thank You transaction URL, but then jumps quickly to a select payment gateway page, which is empty. I need this to go to a different page all together.

How do I add a Redirect the "Select Payment Gateway page" to another inside page ? Also this should not show with $0 fee enabled; instead it should go to a Thank you page automatically.

I have tried Redirection Url's, but it seems with CiviCRM the process is this, and it goes very quickly > so the re-direct does not work, and there still is NO Thank you or Confirmation they are now registered. The members do get in the system though.

A) a Member Signs-Up for FREE - hits the Register button

B) Instead of seeing a Thank You page > it goes very quickly to this page  /siteurl/register/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact

C) then a second later to a "select payment gateway" page - which is empty. There is no page id or anything here (no Url is shown).

= How do I redirect the page, to remove select pymnt gateway - and have it go to a Welcome Members page instead?

It appears it needs to go AFTER part B - otherwise the Transaction is not processed, and no members go into the system.

I've also found that if WP User Account Creation is OFF - The Form processes just fine, and a Thank you page is shown. But there is NO Username or Password block (which we need)...

Comment: hi - is there any chance your PayPal service is not 'standard'?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply.Just checked...it is "standard"...set to "PayPal - Website Payments Standard". I also have the Dummy one on there to.

Comment: In case my comment wasn't clear, or maybe your answer. I mean that if you visit your PayPal account settings, does it confirm that you have a Standard account? I only ask because in one similar situation the outcome was how you described it, and the problem was that the PayPal account did not match the type of PayPal payment processor set up in CiviCRM. But if you did already answer that, then sorry I can't help at this point.

Comment: Need more info: is it your intent to never ask for payment for the Contribution, when you say you're using a custom Profile you mean a contact profile, right (as opposed to just name/email)? Did you uncheck 'Execute real-time monetary transaction' as well as unchecked Contribution Amounts on the 2nd page of Contribution wizard (Amounts) or do you intend to ask for payments? Or is that what you mean by having '$0 fee enabled'? And you configured your Thank You & Receipting page of course..

Comment: a further thought. if you have a $1 membership fee, does civi+paypal perform as expected. is the problem only because you have $0 and the form is then still sending you off to PayPal. is the $0 fee part of a Price Set or just a Membership chosen on the Membership tab of the Contribution Page. I ask because I do recall earlier issues with PayPal/CiviCRM and $0 memberships

Comment: Hi there, yes everything is configured correctly as you say... No intention to ask for payment, as it is a free membership. A welcome email as a thank you is configured. The problem is when the WP user and password boxes are included, the registration page is accepting the new user, but it goes directly to a select payment gateway empty page, rather than saying thankyou, you are now a member of our site. When the WP user boxes are not included, the form goes through fine,

Comment: Hi peterdnz, Yes the PayPal standard is comfirmed in both the registration page, and with the payment processors. We are accepting $0 membership, so a payment processor is not needed. And for your second thought, I haven't yet tested with a $1 because I don't want to pay a $1 for a free membership :), even as a test. Also, all settings are exactly as civicrm demo, on a free membership. The demo goes through fine, mine doesn't. The only difference is I'm using version 4.6.8 and the demo 4.9. I think it may be a bug in the system? Done research and came across another similar instance.

Comment: $1 to confirm if the problem is specific to it being a $0 option seems a cheap test/confirmation to me

Comment: Ok, I will try it..but that still won't explain why $0 membership is going to payment gateway page, which is empty.

Comment: Do you ever want to collect money on this form?

Comment: Hi, no it is a free $0 membership. We will never have a need for payment.

Comment: then i don't understand how paypal is involved at all. if the contribution page is not set to "Execute real-time monetary transactions"